# No qualifying bean when trying to inject JpaRepository into AWS Lambda

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, dependency-injection, aws-lambda

I have an external jar that has `JpaRepository` interfaces. I'm trying to use Spring to autowire it into a simple AWS Lambda. I keep getting

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.some.repository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

JPA repository in external JAR

```
package com.some.repository;

public interface SomeJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<ClassA, Long> {
    ...
}
```

My lambda

```
public class MyLambdaHandler {
    static final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext CONTEXT = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.some.repository");

    @Autowired
    private SomeJpaRepository repository;

    public MyLambdaHandler() {
        CONTEXT.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }
}
```

I've also tried without the `@Autowired` annotation as such

```
    public MyLambdaHandler() {
        this.repository = CONTEXT.getBean(SomeJpaRepository.class);
    }
```

Printing the beans in my application context shows that there is no bean called SomeJpaRepository.

Edit: I do have all the jars in the zip uploaded to AWS

Update: I’ve also tried @EnableJpaRepositories annotation, but that gives the the error of 
No bean named ‘entityManagerFactory’ available

Comment: I see `@Repository` annotation is missing in `SomeJpaRepository` class which is causing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` to be thrown

Comment: I tried adding @Repository annotation, and it still gives the same error

Comment: Use Spring Cloud Function https://dzone.com/articles/run-code-with-spring-cloud-function-on-aws-lambda or correct Spring initialization. Let's start from correct and working schema, not from not working one trying to fix all possible problems there :-)

Comment: If possible, I want to avoid using Spring Cloud Function or more Spring related things.

Answer (score -1):

You need to package all the dependencies with in the AWS lambda deployment package/zip. You cannot refer to an external dependency. If you want to use this dependency as a common dependency acorss different lambda's and don't want to package them with your lambda package, then you can try to make use of [AWS Lambda Layers.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

Comment: I do have all the jars in the zip. Double checked it just now.